# What is 忘れなと a contraction of?

Tags: translation, song-lyrics, contractions, particle-な, context

In Meiko Kaji's song "Jeans Blues" there is a verse containing the 忘れなと phrase:

> 場末の陽気な男達
> 私の涙にもらい泣き
> 酒でもあおって**忘れなと**
> 財布はたいて飲みあかし

I think, it can be neither a contraction of 忘れない + と nor using the な for emphasis. The translation I found is "*Drinking to forget it all*", but I do not see how this can relate to 酒でもあおって忘れなと, unless it is very loose translation. Of course, song texts are often very poetic and thus far away from typical speech, but the rest of the songtext is rather straightforward...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not (necessarily) a contraction, but な meaning imperative (cf. [な](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%81%AA/#je-55709) #2)+ と meaning quote.

It describes what 場末の陽気な男達 says to the writer. Though the connection to the rest of the texts is a bit awkward, it literally says *(saying that) 'Forget by drinking some alcohol'*.

Comment: This is not short for 忘れなさい?

Comment: @JimmyYang Considering な as an ending particle, 忘れな is a full fledged imperative. [なさい](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%AA%E3%81%95%E3%81%84-588615) is not な＋さい (or な+さる).

Comment: ^ 明鏡国語辞典 says 「な〘終助詞〙 ❹《動詞や動詞型活用の助動詞の連用形に付いて》ぞんざいな調子の命令を表す。「ちょっと来な」「やってみな」「やめな」▽ **「なさい」の略。** 」. デジタル大辞泉 also says [here](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%AA/#jn-162177)「な 1⃣ 終助詞 ２ 《補助動詞「なさる」の**命令形「なさい」の省略形** 》動詞・動詞型助動詞の連用形に付く。命令の意を表す。「早く行きな」「好きなようにやりな」」. @Jimmy meant to say that this な is short for なさい (この「な」は「なさい」の省略形), right?